# I want to update firebase database with react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem while trying to update data in the firebase database with my react code.
Most probably my code syntax is not good, so can you help me in some way?

This is my code syntax:

```
const addNewData = async (e) => {


e.preventDefault();

  let data = {
  sifra:sifraRef.current.value,
  naziv:nazivRef.current.value,
  detalji_dijete:detaljiRef.current.value,
  opis:opisRef.current.value,
  broj_obroka:brojObrokaRef.current.value,
  napomena:napomenaRef.current.value
}  
const uuid = uid();
await updateDoc(collection(db, `namirnice/${uuid}`), data)


  close();

  }
```

All these examples I saw on youtube tutorials works...
I hope you can help me.

Comment: "my code syntax is not good" is hard to help with. What happens when you run this code? Is there an error mesage?

Comment: This is a console.log which I get
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but namirnice/5b61b327e2e has 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updateDoc` function is used to update an **existing** document. But since you call `uuid()`, you always get a new value and so you're trying to update a document that doesn't exist yet, which isn't possible.

**To create a new document, use `setDoc` instead of `updateDoc` in your code.**

Also see the Firebase documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#web-version-9)